# What's the main difference between command and trigger? (Xamarin)

Tags: c#, android, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

What is the main difference and the best way to handle a button press event in Xamarin?

Is it by using the command pattern (MVVM) or by implementing a trigger?

Until now, I was always using the command pattern, binding the button with my command, and implementing the "Execute" method.

Recently I've discovered the "triggers", and that events such as "Clicked" can be implemented by a trigger action class.

Command example:

```
    <Button x:Name="loginButton"
            Text="Login"
            Command="{Binding EmailLoginCommand}"
            CommandParameter="{Binding UserLoginInfo}"/>
```

Trigger example:

```
    <EventTrigger Event="Clicked">
            <triggers:UploadMediaButtonTriggerAction />
    </EventTrigger>
```

The trigger reminds me a bit of the `OnClicked` event handler, which is not ideal for generic purposes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each page has a BindingContext, that would be your viewmodel. You can of course write code behind and reference the controls in code but that leaves just leaves you with an app that's a nightmare to maintain and you have UI and business logic all mixed together.

you can have of course have pages with a viewmodel and pages without, most MVVM frameworks allow for this.

Commands are less coupled than events. Think of them as the next evolution of the Event.

For example, on an event you have to subscribe directly to that instance.
`MyClassInstance.SomeEvent += eventHandlerMethod();`

Which most times means you have to know the subscribscription at design time

But a command can be referenced just by name, including in your XAML binding. Meaning its more fluid and will bind to your context at RUNTIME.

```
            <Button HeightRequest="55"
                    Margin="0,7,0,0"
                    VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                    BackgroundColor="Green"
                    Command="{Binding AcceptThisCommand}"
                    CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedDocument}"
                    FontSize="{StaticResource MediumFontSize}"
                    IsVisible="{Binding IsSomethingDoneProperty,
                                        Converter={StaticResource BoolInvertConverter}}"
                    Text="{StaticResource Accept}"
                    TextColor="{StaticResource SecondaryTextColor}"
                    Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleLrg}" />
```

Commands can also take Parameters that again, don't have to be defined at design time. So you can send virtually any run-time object along with the command, and let the handler be concerned with how to interpret it. In the eample above when the command is raised it will carry with it the `SelectedDocument` as a parameter. So while you are clicking a button you are not subscribing to the Button.Click then forced to jump through hoops to handle some specific object. Instead the handler for "AcceptThis" receives the actual document to be accepted. The same command handler can then also be assigned to a menu item... Or ListView selection... Or a network call where a document is downloaded and should then be automatically accepted. All of those other options don't have to know where the command was defined. All of those other options don't have to provide the same parameter object.

When you put all that together it means an 'AcceptThisCommand' can be bound to a photograph in one case and have a photo processor handle it... and bound to a music file in another case and since the handler is from a different context it will know how to handle that data type.

And without the tight binding that events have you can add a new listener FROM the listener without having to know who/where the command is being raise from. You don't have to to know that the `FileDoneDownloadingCommand` is burried deep in `ApplicationVM.Media.Handlers.REST.Services.Transfers` - You just know that you're listening for the command to be raised. Later when someone refactors that service moving the command to a much easier to remember location all of the subscribers to don't break. Making it a far more maintainable architecture.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-bindings-to-mvvm

Comment: Thanks for the information about the command.
So to sum it all up, basically the "trigger" Is equivalent to the event handling? (which is hard to maintain unlike the command)